# how to pass the path that in my navigation function and interface ApiService through PagingSource for paging my app

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hello stack overflow community, I would like to pass the argument of customer id that in my (navigation) function and the path that in the interface (API Service All Vouchers By Customer) function through (All Vouchers By Customer Paging Source) class and other classes below, i want to fetch every customer data by his id and show into detail screen that i should build later.

How can i do that....

here is my code

**Navigation function**

```
  composable(
     route = "Customer_Invoices/{id}",
     arguments = listOf(
        navArgument(name = "id") {
           type = NavType.StringType
        }
     )
  ) {
     All_Vouchers_By_Customer_Screen_WithTopBar(
        navController,
        ID = it.arguments?.getString("id"),
     )
  }
```

**Interface ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer**

```
interface ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer {

  @GET("CustomerInvoices/{id}")
  suspend fun getAllVouchersByCustomer(
      @Path("id") id: Int,
      @Query("page") page: Int,
  ): DataGroup

}
```

**Class AllVouchersByCustomerPagingSource**

```
class AllVouchersByCustomerPagingSource(
  private val apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer: ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer
): PagingSource<Int, Data>() {

   override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Data>): Int? {
       return state.anchorPosition?.let {
           state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
               ?: state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
       }
   }


   override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Data> {
       return try {
           val position = params.key ?: 1

           delay(500)

           val response = apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer
               .getAllVouchersByCustomer(
                   id = xxxxx,
                   page = position
               )

           LoadResult.Page(
               data = response.data,
               //remoteData,
               prevKey = if(position == 1) null else position.minus(1),
               nextKey = if(response.data.isEmpty()) null else position.plus(1)
           )
       }
       catch (e:IOException){
           LoadResult.Error(e)
       }
       catch (e:HttpException){
           LoadResult.Error(e)
       }
   }



}
```

**Repository: class AllVouchersByCustomerRepo**

```
class AllVouchersByCustomerRepo(
private val apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer: ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer) {

  fun getAllVouchersByCustomerStream() = Pager(
      config = PagingConfig(
          pageSize = 5,
          //prefetchDistance = 5,
          //enablePlaceholders = false,
          //initialLoadSize = 5
      ),
      pagingSourceFactory = {
          AllVouchersByCustomerPagingSource(
              apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer
          )
      }
  ).flow

}
```

**ViewModel: class AllVouchersByCustomerViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class AllVouchersByCustomerViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val allVouchersByCustomerRepo: AllVouchersByCustomerRepo) : ViewModel() {

    fun getDDDD(): Flow<PagingData<Data>> =
        allVouchersByCustomerRepo
            .getAllVouchersByCustomerStream()
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

**AppModules: object AppModules_AllVouchersByCustomer**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object AppModules_AllVouchersByCustomer {

   private const val BASE_URL = "https://xisaabso.online/"
   @Provides
   fun provideAPiService_AllVouchersByCustomer(): ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer {
       return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
         .create())
         .build()
         .create(ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer::class.java)
   }

   @Provides
   fun provideAllVouchersByCustomerRepo(
      apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer: ApiService_AllVouchersByCustomer
   ):AllVouchersByCustomerRepo {

      return AllVouchersByCustomerRepo(apiserviceAllvouchersByCustomer)

   }



}
```